# Cannot interpret token '.' at position 5 in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am using `datatable.compute`  where the formula is stored in xml file retrieved dynamically.Now i am getting error as Cannot interpret token '.' at position 5 in asp.net, all are decimal and i dont know why i am getting this error for `FORMULA=(0.7.0*1000.0*30.0*115.0)/(1000.0)`

```
decimal dec= ((decimal)(dt.Compute(FORMULA, ""))).Normalize();


public static class Extensionclass
{
    public static decimal Normalize(this decimal value)
    {
        return value / 1.000000000000000000000000000000000m;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first part of the formula (`0.7.0`) is *not a valid decimal*.

Comment: What do i have to do here ,since everything is coming from databace.What would be the generic solution since i am doing complex calcluation contain big numbers

Comment: @peter What do you mean? Your data in the database is wrong.

Comment: @peter That depends on what `0.7.0` should be. We can´t tell you what that "number" should mean. If that was insrted by user-control, I suppose you have a low validation for the input, which won´t check such errors.

Comment: That is entered by user by using another aplplication.so i cannot control it rather adjusting from my side ,i changed to float, but not working

Comment: @peter Does 0.7.0 mean something? You'll need to write code to convert it to a form that lets you convert it to a float, if that's the correct thing to do. If it doesn't mean anything, then I'd throw that data out as bad because it's not a number.

Comment: then which datatype is fit for 0.7??

Comment: @peter double, decimal, and float are fit for 0.7, but you don't have 0.7, you have 0.7.0

Answer (score 0):

some how i managed like if value less than 1,first i will multiply by 10 and then finally after datatable.compute, for those whose value less than 1 again i will divide by 10,thanks all